# What is the significance behind having small kernel sizes over having one large kernel size that covers the entire input in a CNN?

Tags: machine-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, image-processing, convolutional-layers, filters

I have hardly ever seen anyone cover the entire input image with a filter of the same dimensions. I was wondering why that is the case, and if the performance in say, an image detection application would decrease if someone used `kernel size = the size of the input image` itself?

Comment: What is the output in this case? It is a single real number?

Comment: @hanugm Sure, let's assume that it has a two cases - one with a single real-valued output and the other a probability output vector of size 'n'